# Excel VBA - Number format seems unchangeable

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table which is straight from a database. Its first column contain dates but are not formatted as dates. They are written as : 03/01/2014 for example.
So I'm trying to comparing values from some cells and the problem is people type dates as : 3/01/2014. When comparing the values no value is returned. I'm using the range.find() command. So I tried to change the format of the date column in the table but it didn't change at all. However if I try to edit a cell and just press enter it becomes a normal date. I wonder if there is a way I can convert all those rigid dates in the table to normal excel dates so that the comparison routine can work.
Thanks you.

Comment: What format would you like the result to have??

Comment: I want all the values in the date column of the table to be in date format "m/d/yyyy".

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that if you use the value function it will convert the text 03/01/2014 to its equivalent numeric value. So what I want is to apply the value function to all the rows of column DATE and change the formatting to data.

Comment: Is there a way I can ignore the 0 in the date values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells whose dates you wish to convert and run this small macro:

```
Sub DateSetter()
Dim r As Range, d As Date, st As String
For Each r In Selection
    st = r.Text
    If InStr(st, "/") <> 0 Then
        ary = Split(st, "/")
        d = DateSerial(CInt(ary(2)), CInt(ary(1)), CInt(ary(0)))
        r.Clear
        r.Value = d
        r.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

It should perform the conversion, but ignore zeros, blanks, and other junk.